# Ubuntu core: snapd has no slot named "audio-playback"

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, ubuntu-core

I am trying to play a video from YouTube using the mir-kiosk and wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk, but there is no sound while the video plays. I tried playing a local video file with mpv kiosk but ran into the same issue.

I have traced the problem to there being no slot for audio-playback in snapd. I checked the connections using "snap connections snapd" and found no slots for audio-playback. There is a plug wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk:pulseaudio in wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk, but the slot is empty:

[image: (screenshot)]

I also looked into pulseaudio and installed the snap, but I don't know how to connect it to wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk this is what I tried this:

[image: screenshot]

but wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk has no plug for pulseaudio and I don't know how to add it.

How do I go about solving this issue? I am on Ubuntu core 20 and quite new to snaps and Ubuntu core.